# Click do Mouse sem mover o Cursor da Tela

Tags: delphi

Estou fazendo um sistema simples, nesse FORM tem 2 button, um que executa a função e outro que botei um `SHOWMESSAGE('teste ok');` e peguei a POSIÇÃO desse segundo BUTTON, lembrando que preciso usar o `SENDMESSAGE` para o CURSOR do MOUSE não mover na tela, então fiz o seguinte programa:

```
Procedure SendMouseClick(x,y:Integer);
var
h:THandle;
begin
h := FindWindow(nil, 'TForm1');
SendMessage(h, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x,y));
sleep(10);
SendMessage(h, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x,y));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
SendMouseClick(1042,538);
end;
```

Acontece que eu clico e simplesmente não faz nada no meu FORM. O que posso estar errando?

Answer (score 3):

Talvez eu tenha entendido errado, mas pelo que eu entendi você quer apenas disparar a função do click do 2o botão.
Se for isto, basta chamar a função diretamente.
Exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button2Click(Sender);  // pode ser chamada em qualquer lugar, em uma outra função, em um timer, em um evento OnClick do form...
  // Se for o caso em algumas funções não terás o Sender, basta substituir por qualquer outro objeto. Sender identifica que objeto está "disparando" o click.
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar [Mouse_Event](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/mouseadvanced.htm)

{Move o mouse}

```
Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, COORDENADA X, COORDENADA Y, 0, 0);
```

{Simula o pressionamento do botãoesquerdo do mouse}

```
Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, COORDENADA X, COORDENADA Y, 0, 0);
```

{ Simula soltando o botãoesquerdo do mouse }

```
Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, COORDENADA X, COORDENADA Y, 0, 0);
```

Fote: http://www.devmedia.com.br/delphi-simular-clique-do-mouse/12109

Comment: Amigo, o Mouse_Event infelizmente MOVE O CURSOR do mouse. Eu gostaria de usar o SENDMESSAGE ou o POSTMESSAGE que não "move" o Cursor entende ?

Comment: Então tente colocar FindWindow('TForm1', nil)

Comment: Colocar FindWindow aonde ? Usando o Mouse_Event ? Ou o SendMessage ? Se for com o SENDMESSAGE eu já fiz ali em cima, veja lá..obrigado!

Comment: Tente inverter os parametros de h := FindWindow(nil, 'TForm1'); para h := FindWindow('TForm1', nil);

Comment: Testei agora, mesma coisa amigo, simplesmente não faz nada na tela....h := FindWindow('TForm1', nil);

Answer (score 1):

No evento `OnClick` do `Button1` coloque o seguinte código:

```
SendMessage(Button2.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, 0); 
SendMessage(Button2.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, 0);
```

Isto vai fazer que ao clicar no `Button1` será enviado a mensagem [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para o *handle* do `Button2`. A mensagem [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) é utilizada quando o usuário *pressiona* o botão esquerdo do mouse, já a mensagem [`WM_LBUTTONUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) é usada quando queremos *soltar* o botão esquerdo do mouse.

Para ficar mais organizado crie um procedimento que faça isso.

```
procedure SimularClick(H: HWND);
begin
SendMessage(H, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, 0); 
SendMessage(H, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, 0);
end;
```

No `OnClick` do `Button` basta chamar:

```
SimularClick(Button2.Handle);
```

Boa sorte.

Comment: Amigo, obrigado ela resposta....e se eu quiser clicar em uma determinada posição fora do FORM, como eu devo fazer ?

Comment: @user7605 O StackOverflow não é como um fórum. Se a resposta satisfez sua pergunta você deveria aceitá-la como resposta. Se você quer uma resposta um pouco diferente, altere sua pergunta incluindo o que você precisa. Se você precisa de fazer outra pergunta então, bem... faça outra pergunta.

Comment: Já alterei a minha pergunta amigo!!